# How to format dates with momentjs like SO?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, formatdatetime

StackOwerflow formates post's create time like the following:

```
asked 58 secs ago
asked 1 min ago 
asked 13 hours ago
asked yesterday
asked 2 days ago
asked Jun 22 at 11:13
```

I want to make something like this with my [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). What format string should I use to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Calculating_elapsed_time

Comment: With moment, use the fromNow feature: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: Clearly didn't read the manual thoroughly

Comment: As you can see from the documentation momentjs generates some different output than I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a date saved in a variable, for example `myDate`, this task is very simple with 'momentJS'.

If `myDate` is in `YYYYMMDD` format simply call the 'momentJS' `fromNow` function like so:

```
moment(myDate, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

Please reference [this section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) of the 'momentJS' docs for further details. I highly recommend reading through the docs of the library you're attempting to use before posting questions to StackOverflow as well. If you're still stumped after reading through the docs then posting here is a great next option :)

Note: If you want to tweak the 'momentJS' `fromNow` function you could add a custom `fromNowCustom` function with something like this:

```
moment.fn.fromNowCustom = function(a) {
  if (/*whatever scenario you're customizing for*/) {
    return /*custom output*/;
  } else {
    return this.fromNow(a);
  }
};
```

...then reference it like so:

```
moment(myDate, "YYYYMMDD").fromNowCustom();
```

Comment: As you can see from the documentation momentjs generates some different output than I need.

Comment: @Erik: The output within the "Time from now" section I linked to looks exactly the same to me. Could you clarify what is different about it?

Comment: for example `moment().fromNow()` outputs `a few seconds ago` but I need `asked 1 secs ago`

Comment: @Erik, just added details to my answer above